# How does the supplier.get() function assign list value to the PageInfo object when there is no variable defined to capture supplier.get() value?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

The following code is in working state but I don't get it how supplier.get() value is being assigned to PageInfo object which is later being retrieved in the code stated after function pageQueryWithCount.

```
public static <T> PageInfo<T> pageQueryWithCount(int pageNum, int pageSize, Supplier<List<T>> supplier) {
    if(pageNum < 1 ) pageNum = 1;
    if(pageSize < 1 ) pageSize = 8;
    try {
        Page<T> page = PageHelper.startPage(pageNum, pageSize, true);
        supplier.get();
        return new PageInfo<T>(page);
    } finally {
        PageHelper.clearPage();
    }
}

PageInfo<RedMainInfoBO> pageInfo = PageUtils.pageQueryWithCount(pageNum,pageSize,()->{
            return redPacketInfDao.getExpiredRecord(endDateTime,startDateTime,BnsStsEnum.SUCCESS.getCode());
        });

        List<RedMainInfoBO> list=pageInfo.getList();
```

Comment: It can't be said without seeing the actual implementation of that supplier. But what I suspect is that the ".get()" is not simply retrieving a value, it's also doing some other stuff and the only way you have to guess it is to check what is the implementation of that supplier you're passed.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Supplier implementation is given in the code above, let me mention in the comment again `()->{
            return redPacketInfDao.getExpiredRecord(endDateTime,startDateTime,BnsStsEnum.SUCCESS.getCode());
        });
`

Comment: And the getExpiredRecord method is as below: `List<RedMainInfoBO> getExpiredRecord(@Param("endDateTime") LocalDateTime endDateTime, @Param("startDateTime")LocalDateTime startDateTime, @Param("code")String code);`